# Why is Web3.js estimating 0 GWEI for gas price on Sepolia?

Tags: gas-price, sepolia

**For some reason Web3.js cannot estimate gas correctly on Sepolia**

I have pulled in the Web3.js library via CDN

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3js-cdn@1.3.0/web3.min.js"></script>`

From my front end I am invoking a contract function via Metamask

```
transactionReceipt = await tokenFactoryContract.methods.deployMinterPauserToken("name", "symbol", "1", "1", "1")
.send({
   from: selectedAccount,
   value: web3.utils.toWei("0.2", "ether"),
});
```

When Metamask pops up is says

```
Site suggested
Gas (estimated) $0.00
0 Sepolia ETH
Unknown processing time
Max fee: 0 SepoliaETH
```

I intentionally left out the gas price from the contract invocation, so why is it failing to estimate the gas properly? I am also surprised that is says `Site suggested` when the site is definitely NOT suggesting a gas price.

[Update]

When I deploy the contract on Polygon, Metamask is able to accurately infer the gas price using the same Web3.js and contract invocation code.